# Get table tools in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

When using TinyMCE, I try to activate the [table tools](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:table). However, when I add the tabletools to my configuration, a set of 'empty' buttons show up, see:
[image]

(right top)

This is the code:

```
$('.tinymce').tinymce({
script_url : 'js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js',
content_css : 'css/tinymce.css',
language : "en",
mode : "textareas",
theme : "advanced",
skin : "o2k7",
fix_list_elements : true,
verify_css_classes:true,
plugins : "paste,fullscreen,table",
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,undo,redo,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bul    list,numlist,formatselect,fontselect,tablecontrols",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pasteword,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,link,unlink,anchor,InsertImageBtn,cleanup,|,forecol    or,backcolor,hr,removeformat,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,fullscreen",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
valid_elements : "img[src|alt|title],a[href|target|title],-p,strong/b,em/i,-ul,-ol,-li,-table[!border:1|!cellspacing:0|!cellpadding:5    ],th,-tr,td,p[class],span[class]",
paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
fix_table_elements : true,
plugins : "-insert",
width:750,
height:500
});
```

The table plugin is present in the plugin folder, I get no javascript error whatsoever, and I just installed the latest TinyMCE version. Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: +1 did you examine the "buttons" using firebug?

Comment: @Thariama: just checked them out; they are only the separators, not the buttons themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have two plugin elements in your config. The second one:

```
plugins : "-insert",
```

...is overwriting the first and so you only load the local "insert" plugin. You can combine both lists into the one config element and it should work correctly.